# Analyzing survey data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have multiple surveys with the same 3 questions, each one has 5 options for a response, from strongly disagree->strongly agree. I have combined multiple surveys from the same month into a single data frame and am trying to create a table that compares the relative frequency of each response. Below is the desired outcome:
image:
[Desired Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY7AF.png)

I am having trouble with figuring out how to get R to count the number of unique event names and then creating the table above. I have been able to do this on a survey by survey basis, but instead of comparing Q1,Q2,Q3 results, I want to compare the results for each event's Q1, Q2, and Q3.

Here is some of my dput:

```r
dput(cleandata[c(1,400,600,1000,2000,3000),])
structure(list(`Event Name` = c("A",
"A",
"A",
"B",
"C", "D"
), `Attendance Duration` = c("65.0 mins", "65.0 mins", "57.0 mins",
"54.0 mins", "58.0 mins", "58.0 mins"), `Survey Score` = c(14,
15, 15, 15, 14, 11), `The content was delivered in an understable manner` = c("Strongly agree",  ## this is question 1
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree",
"Neutral"), `Overall, the content was applicable to  activities` = c("Strongly agree",  ## this is question 2
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree",
"Agree"), `Aspects of this training can be used in the daily work ` = c("Agree",  ## this is question 3
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Agree",
"Agree")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"))
```

```r
dput(cleandata[10:20,])
structure(list(`Event Name` = c("A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A", 
"A"
), `Attendance Duration` = c("60.0 mins", "68.0 mins", "63.0 mins", 
"59.0 mins", "54.0 mins", "58.0 mins", "60.0 mins", "57.0 mins", 
"49.0 mins", "44.0 mins", "59.0 mins"), `Survey Score` = c(12, 
14, 15, 13, 15, 15, 15, 12, 15, 14, 12), `The content was delivered in an understable manner` = c("Agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Strongly agree", 
"Agree", "Agree"), `Overall, the content was applicable to activities` = c("Agree", 
"Agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Agree"), `Aspects of this training can be used in the daily work ` = c("Agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Neutral", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
"Strongly agree", "Agree")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
cleandata %>%
  count(`Event Name`, `Overall, the content was applicable to  activities`) %>%
  group_by(`Event Name`) %>%
  mutate(share = (n / sum(n)) %>% scales::percent()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `Overall, the content was applicable to  activities`,
              values_from = share, values_fill = "0%")


  `Event Name` `Strongly agree` Agree
  <chr>        <chr>            <chr>
1 A            100%             0%   
2 B            100%             0%   
3 C            100%             0%   
4 D            0%               100%
```

It might be easier and more resilient if you can include multiple quarters of data so you can calculate them together once. You might also look at converting your responses (currently character data) into ordered factors (one way: https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_relevel.html) so that you can sort them more automatically downstream.

Comment: Hi Jon, I'm getting this error when I try to use this. I actually have written code that replaces the response options with 1,2,3,4,5 and stores them as Q1Val/Q2Val/Q3Val

```r
Error: Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = cleandata$`Event Name``.
i `..1` must be size 28 or 1, not 3823.
```

Comment: I presume this is on a larger or different set of data than your sample? Can you include a sample of data that produces this error?

Comment: Sure, one second.